# change TextBox.Text before scanning AutoComplete

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to customize Autocomplete in Textbox. I want to change the text `a` into `á` before the `Autocomplete` dropbox is executed. Here what you try to do :

```
//when I type 'a' in the textbox
 //I would like the autocomplete giving me this

 - á
```

Is it possible to do this? Could anyone show the way so I can do and learn how to do this? Any help is REALLY appreciated ! THANK YOU !

Comment: You could handle this directly in an EventHandler of the `TextBox.TextChanged` event.

Comment: Thank for reply, @MrPaulch ! But I need the TextBox keep it's old value `a`.

Comment: So then let it keep the old value... I don't really get your problem.